# How to hide contacts menu in Odoo v12 (only users in a cerain group will be allowed to se it)?

Tags: python, odoo

In odoo i have created a custom module, with two roles "stores" and "managers". I want to hide the Odoo Contacts app menu from those "store" users. I have tried with the following code, but the Contacts menu is still showing. What can I do to hide that menu?

```
 <record model="ir.ui.menu" id="contacts.menu_contacts">
        <field name="groups">mymodule.manager</field>
  </record>

 <record model="ir.ui.menu" id="contacts.res_partner_menu_contacts">
      <field name="groups">mymodule.manager</field>
  </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello to limit access of the view you can use the field "groups_id"

```
<record model="ir.ui.menu" id="contacts.menu_contacts"  >
         <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ ref('mymodule.manager')])]"/>
  </record>

 <record model="ir.ui.menu" id="contacts.res_partner_menu_contacts">
      <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ ref('mymodule.manager')])]"/>
 </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ create your security group

2/ inherit the menu and add to security group

3/ add users to the security group